# Create shape in xlsx report using python in odoo?

Tags: xlsx, odoo-15

I need to **generate square shape in xlsx report using python** in odoo15?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only TextBox is supported

You can find the answer at [feature request: Implement Shapes[arrows, boxes, rectangles]](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/872#issuecomment-1109944042). The creator of the `XlsxWriter` says that this is not possible and will not be added.

> **jmcnamara** commented on Apr 26, 2022
> I think this probably isn't feasible. There are too many shapes to support and provide APIs for. It is also not a very frequently requested feature so the cost-benefit value is low.
> So, for now, this is a won't/can't add. Sorry.